# How can multiple robots communicate using ROS?

Tags: ros, communication, multi-robot, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For many applications, communication between robots is necessary. What is currently the recommended best practice for achieving that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9135/how-can-multiple-robots-communicate-using-ros?/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is currently no best practice for multiple robots, but there are some commonly used tools for different configurations:

- [foreign_relay](http://www.ros.org/wiki/foreign_relay): shuttles data between distinct ROS systems.
- [zenmaster_sd](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Repositories#multimaster-ros-pkg): uses bonjour to sync data between multiple masters
- [wifi_comm](http://www.ros.org/wiki/wifi_comm): combines foreign_relay with discovery

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pacifica](https://answers.ros.org/users/1187/pacifica/) on 2012-12-04**:
Hi kwc! Can you tell me if  these 3 configurations are running in ros fuerte??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming all those robots are running ROS, [doing like this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) should be the right solution, I suppose.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-02-20**:
Hi tom, this is indeed a valid answer, it is however not advisable to have multiple robots use a single master, at least in the real world where wireless connections and other factors make that this a very brittle solution.

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-02-20**:
That page is a good starting point but seems geared more towards a 2-machine setup. If one of the machines is an off-board laptop then that's still only one robot. This seems to be an area of active development and one of the areas of focus in a project underway at WG (search for BuildingManager...)